# Powershell - Query Calendar Activities

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm able to successfully create a session to an Exchange server on the same network.

```
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/PowerShell -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $credential
Import-PSSession -Session $session
```

However, as soon as the GetNameSpace method executes then **the Microsoft Outlook 2010 Wizard starts**?

```
$folder = 9
$app = New-Object -Com Outlook.Application
$ns = $app.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$default = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($folder)
```

I get the feeling that it's probably some small conceptual thing that I'm not getting.

Please assist

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK The Outlook Wizard starts if no default profile has been set yet. Is that the case here?

Comment: Yes, this solved it. Thanks Theo
I can't mark your comment as the solution:)

Comment: Ah, yes. A comment cannot be accepted, so I also added it as Answer if you don't mind. I'm doing this because I find too many answers are in fact given in comments like this one, leaving the question marked as unanswered. When answered and accepted, other people may find it easier if they have the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook Wizard starts if no default profile has been set yet.

When going through that wizard one time and have it create such a profile, the code should work.